# Missing ) after argument list Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to run some javascript but I'm getting the following error: `missing ) after argument list`. I'm wondering can anyone tell me where I'm  going wrong.

```
$('<div id=dojoUnique1 class='dojoDndItem filterName' style=padding:.5em;display:inline-block;width:16em;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:bottom;>filter_info_ALL_DATA_DOWN</div>').appendTo('#selectedFilters');
```

Comment: Just a note: `filter_info_ALL_DATA_DOWN` looks like a variable, if so you need to concatenate this in your string using the `+` - operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using simple quotes twice in a row...
escape quotes:

```
"$('<div id=dojoUnique1 class=\"dojoDndItem filterName\" style=padding:.5em;display:inline-block;width:16em;overflow:hidden;vertical-align:bottom;>filter_info_ALL_DATA_DOWN</div>').appendTo('#selectedFilters');"
```

Comment: if you use double quotes inside single quotes, there is no need to escape them. Furthermore the qoutes around `style` are missing

Comment: yes i know but he edit his post to remove the wrapping double quotes.. so yes indeed, no need to escape

Answer (score 1):

You have mis-matched `'` delimiting your string. If you use an editor with syntax highlighting errors like this are easy to spot. Try this:

```
$('<div id="dojoUnique1" class="dojoDndItem filterName" style="padding: .5em; display: inline-block; width: 16em; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: bottom;">filter_info_ALL_DATA_DOWN</div>').appendTo('#selectedFilters');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create elements using jQuery, which is lot safer that quotes mess and more maintainable.

*Here is an example*

```
$('<div />')
    .prop('id', 'dojoUnique1')
    .addClass('dojoDndItem filterName')
    .css({
        "padding" : "0.5em",
        "display" : "inline-block"
    })
    .html("filter_info_ALL_DATA_DOWN")
    .appendTo('#selectedFilters');
```

Comment: Is it possible to use these elements in selenium webdriver scripts?